# Barcode Bar width adjustment with nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, jsbarcode

Is it possible to do bar width adjustment with [Jsbarcode](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode) library? To create a barcode now, we are using software called "Barcode producer" They had an option called bar width adjustment, which can be set from (-23 to +23), which actually decreases the bar width.

[image: barcode producer image]

Now is it possible to do the same with this library? I am kinda stuck cause when I am printing on plastic because the bars are too wide, so it overlaps. That's why in the Axicon verifier it's grading at "C". I need to get at least a "B". I am not getting any luck changing the "width" property even If I use 1 it's wider I need to below 1. But if I change the barcode width to -4 in barcode producer I am getting an "B". Is it possible to do it using any other library other than this? Even if the library is in other languages, that won't be a problem

I tried with multiple libraries but not able to decrease the bar width.